# How do I implement a child context (CoreData) in SwiftUI environment?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm currently learning SwiftUI to further include it in my daily UIKit-based workflow. I got to a point where I can not get a concept running in SwiftUI, that I've been using for years in UIKit.

The idea is to use a child context of my main CoreData `managedObjectContext` for editing entities. I implement it quite basically by doing the following:

```
// Get view context of application
let viewContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

// Create NSManagedObjectContext
let editingContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

// Set the parent of the editing context to the main view context
editingContext.parent = viewContext
```

By using a separate `editingContext` I can make changes to an entity in it without the change proceeding directly to my main context. If the user chooses to abort the change, I just reset the `editingContext`.

For the implementation in SwiftUI, I chose to implement the editingContext as an environment object by creating a custom `EnvironmentKey`:

```
struct EditingContextKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var editingContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        get {
            return self[EditingContextKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[EditingContextKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then the `editingContext` is added to my root view:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
    .environment(\.editingContext, editingContext)
```

To this point everything works fine. I also can use the `editingContext` by calling the following in the respective view.

```
@Environment(\.editingContext) var editingContext
```

However, as soon as I make changes to the entity in the `editingContext` and try to save the `editingContext`, I get an unexpected error:

```
Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)", [:]: file
```

I did already checked, if the context of the edited entity is matching the `editingContext`. This seems to be the case. I have the feeling, it could have something to do with a binding in SwiftUI, but have no idea how to approach finding a solution.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Or is my basic approach to the desired functionality wrong and there is a more convenient way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Lars for this nice solution. I tried it myself and it works nicely. I do not have any crash when saving the content of the editingContext. Tested on iOS and macOS. Do you have a more complete example project where you see this problem? (e.g. based on Apples CoreData template)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your approach, I would not recommend injecting two different contexts at the same time into a single view's environment. It's best to have a clear mental picture of whether the view is in the main view context territory or the editing child context territory. If we are working with a view that we know is driven by a nested context, merely dismissing that view will clear out its struct from memory, destroy its context, and thus discard our changes.

We also have to be mindful of where we create our nested contexts. The mistake I used to make is creating a nested context inside a `.sheet` modifier like so:

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingItemEditor) {
    makeItemEditor()
}

func makeItemEditor() -> some View {
     let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
     childContext.parent = viewContext
     let childItem = Item(context: childContext)
     return ItemEditor(item: childItem)
         .environment(\.managedObjectContext, childContext)
}
```

It works fine at first, but the system might call `.sheet` modifier many times, and we'll be creating new child contexts for the same operation. As we scale, this might cause the user to lose their changes when the app moves to the background, failures establishing relationships between objects because they are in different contexts.

To remedy this, we can store our nested context, and a newly created object in that context, in a dedicated structure like this:

```swift
struct CreateOperation<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    let object: Object
    
    init(withParentContext parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        object = Object(context: childContext)
    }
}
```

Now to create a new object and present accompanying UI for editing, we simply need to create an instance of that structure.

```swift
struct ItemList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State private var configuration: CreateOperation<Item>?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.name ?? "")
                }
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $configuration) { configuration in
            ItemEditor(item: configuration.object)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, configuration.childContext)
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        configuration = CreateOperation(withParentContext: viewContext)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ItemEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: Binding($item.name)!)
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Item")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Save") {
                    try? context.save()
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is such a concise, clear answer. The generic in CreateOperation is sweet. Any chance you could extend it to show editing an existing object and canceling (dismissing without saving) both new and existing objects?  I am finding that most examples don't take it that far and it's not completely obvious how to proceed.

Comment: Glad to be of help, Rick! Check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71368996/7337547), it touches on update operation. To see dismissing without saving, check out this [sample project](https://github.com/genebogdanovich/ChildContextsForEditing/tree/main/ChildContextsForEditing). If you have any more questions, ask away.

Comment: Sample project was very educational. Very clear, very reusable. It seems "very SwiftUI" to me. I like how you overrode the managedObjectContext environment object in the editing context; it keeps everything easy to reason about. Thanks for sharing your work.

Comment: I am so happy I found this example. Thanks for posting.

Comment: You wrote the sheet modifier could get called many times. Doesn't it get called only when it appears so that the child context always gets thrown away when the sheet disappears? Perhaps I didnt understand it right.

Comment: The child context goes out of memory when the view does. In terms of the sheet modifier, you have to test it yourself. I’m just talking from the point of my personal experience.

Comment: So there is no need to clear the child or something like this when the sheet gets closed, so there are not many Childs in memory when opening the sheet some times? What if not working with a sheet, is it enough to set the @State variable with "createOperation" back to nil?

Comment: Yeah, every time you set something to nil it should go out of memory. If the view (sheet, full screen cover) owns the context, when you close that sheet all its properties should go out of memory because the sheet goes out of memory itself. All of this memory stuff is the responsibility of ARC so you might want to dig into that.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  I found it quite useful, though I think I only understand a portion of it.  Now my app saves the data when it should, and not when it shouldn't... as long as it's running.  When I kill the app and run again, any changes I made are gone.  To me, that says that there was some kind of problem saving to the correct context or something like that... but I don't understand MOCs or SwiftUI to be able to really tell.  Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: Answering my own question, in case someone else heads here, I saw from your other answer (referenced in your comment above) that "Since you’re now using child contexts, don’t forget to save your main view context somewhere too, like when the user navigates out of your app."  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a child context like this:

```
struct ItemEditorConfig: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    let item: Item
    
    init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext, objectID: NSManagedObjectID) {
        // create the scratch pad context
        context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = viewContext
        // load the item into the scratch pad
        item = context.object(with: objectID) as! Item
    }
}

struct ItemEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item // this is the scratch pad item
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss // causes body to run
    let onSave: () -> Void
    @State var errorMessage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                    Text(errorMessage)
                }
                Button("Update Time") {
                    item.timestamp = Date()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        // first save the scratch pad context then call the handler which will save the view context.
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            errorMessage = nil
                            onSave()
                        } catch {
                            let nsError = error as NSError
                            errorMessage  = "Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditItemButton: View {
    let itemObjectID: NSManagedObjectID
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var itemEditorConfig: ItemEditorConfig?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: edit) {
            Text("Edit")
        }
        .sheet(item: $itemEditorConfig, onDismiss: didDismiss) { config in
            ItemEditor(item: config.item) {
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
                itemEditorConfig = nil // dismiss the sheet
            }
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, config.context)
        }
    }
    
    func edit() {
        itemEditorConfig = ItemEditorConfig(viewContext: viewContext, objectID: itemObjectID)
    }
    
    func didDismiss() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditItemButton(itemObjectID: item.objectID)
                }
            }
    }
}
```