# How to pass a CoreData model item into a view for editing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a minimal sample project at [CDPassingQ](https://github.com/ericg-xcode-questions/CDPassingQ)

My main ([ContentView](https://github.com/ericg-xcode-questions/CDPassingQ/blob/main/CDPassingQ/ContentView.swift)) looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment( \.managedObjectContext ) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: [ NSSortDescriptor( keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true ) ],
                   animation:       .default )
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach( items ) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        NameViewer( itemID: item.objectID )
                    } label: {
                        Text( item.name! )
                    }
                }
                .onDelete( perform: deleteItems )
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem( placement: .navigationBarTrailing ) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button() {
                        print( "Add Item" )
                    } label: {
                        NavigationLink {
                            NameViewer();
                        } label: {
                            Label( "Add Item", systemImage: "plus" )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

and [NameViewer](https://github.com/ericg-xcode-questions/CDPassingQ/blob/main/CDPassingQ/NameViewer.swift) looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

enum TrustReason: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable
{
    var id: UUID
    {
        return UUID();
    }
    
    case unknown         = "Unknown";
    case legalOnly       = "Legal Only";
    case goodLabeling    = "Good Labeling";
    case facilityClean   = "Facility Clean";
    case detailedAnswers = "Detailed Answers";
    case unresponsive    = "Unresponsive";
}



extension TrustReason
{
    var title: String
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .unknown:
                return "Unknown";
                
            case .legalOnly:
                return "Legal Only";
                
            case .goodLabeling:
                return "Good Labeling";
                
            case .facilityClean:
                return "Facility Clean";
                
            case .detailedAnswers:
                return "Detailed Answers";
                
            case .unresponsive:
                return "Unresponsive";
        }
    }
}



struct NameViewer: View {
    @Environment( \.presentationMode )     var         presentationMode
    @Environment( \.managedObjectContext ) private var moc
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var reason: TrustReason = .unknown

    var itemID: NSManagedObjectID?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section( header: Text( "Information" ) ) {
                TextField( "Name", text: $name )
            }
            
            Section( header: Text( "Trust" ) ) {
                Picker( "Reason", selection: $reason ) {
                    ForEach( TrustReason.allCases ) { trustReason in
                        Text( trustReason.title ).tag( trustReason )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button() {
                if ( saveName() ) {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            } label: {
                Text( "Save" )
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            print( "on appear" )
            
            guard let theID = itemID,
                  let item = moc.object( with: theID ) as? Item else {
                      return
                  }
            
            print( "passed guard" )
            
            if let itemName = item.name {
                name = itemName
            }
            
            print( name )
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private func saveName() -> Bool {
        let item = Item( context: moc )
        
        do {
            print( self.name )
            
            item.name = self.name
            
            try moc.save()
            
            return true
        } catch {
            print( error )
            print( error.localizedDescription )
        }
        
        self.moc.rollback();
        
        return false
    }
}



struct NameViewer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NameViewer()
    }
}
```

I can create new items to be displayed in the list in ContentView.

Then, when I select an item in the list, I am passing that item to NameViewer. I can confirm that I am successfully finding the correct object in the .onAppear code.

However, there are two problems:

1. If I select an item in the list, the item name does not appear in the Name TextField unless I click in the text field first.'
2. Using .onAppear does not seem to be the right place to put that code. The reason is the Picker pushes another view onto the stack and once the item is picked, .onAppear runs again and I lose changes name to the name field.

How can I change the code to resolve these issues?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson and then what? I have updated my code to pass the item, but am still experiencing issues. See the edited question.

Comment: Why? It is what https://www.raywenderlich.com/27201015-dynamic-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-for-ios did. Yes, I am aware that the save code isn't working. I would like to get the data passing working first and will focus on the save once that works.

Comment: I tried passing in the whole object ( `var item: Item?` ), but the described behavior did not change.

Comment: You asked me why I was passing in the objectID and I pointed to the tutorial...I was just doing what it did. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, do plan on upgrading the code to use a view model eventually, but did not want to deal with that extra complication which would make no difference in how things are working.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn’t work and is unnecessary as it is already inside a navigation view coming from the content view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement the desired functionality, I would alter your architecture both on the UI and Core Data sides.

In terms of the user interface, it is best to use navigation links for displaying static data detail views and use modals to carry out data operations, such as creating and editing objects. So have one view to display object detail (e.g. `NameViewer`) and another to edit objects (e.g. `NameEditor`). Also, bind properties of your `NSManagedObject` subclasses directly to SwiftUI controls. Don’t create extra `@State` properties and then copy over the values. You’re introducing a shared state, something that SwiftUI is there to eliminate.

On the Core Data side, in order to perform create and update operations, you need to use child contexts. Any time you’re creating or updating your objects show a modal editor view with child context injected. That way if we’re unhappy with our changes, we can simply dismiss that modal and changes are magically discarded without ever needing to call `rollback()`, since that child context gets destroyed with the view. Since you’re now using child contexts, don’t forget to save your main view context somewhere too, like when the user navigates out of your app.

So to implement that in code, we need some structs to store our newly created objects as well as child contexts for them:

```swift
struct CreateOperation<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    let childObject: Object
    
    init(with parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        let childObject = Object(context: childContext)
        
        self.childContext = childContext
        self.childObject = childObject
    }
}

struct UpdateOperation<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    let childObject: Object
    
    init?(
        withExistingObject object: Object,
        in parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    ) {
        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        guard let childObject = try? childContext.existingObject(with: object.objectID) as? Object else { return nil }
        
        self.childContext = childContext
        self.childObject = childObject
    }
}
```

And the UI code is as follows:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true)], animation: .default
    ) private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State private var itemCreateOperation: CreateOperation<Item>?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        NameViewer(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.name ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                    Button(action: {
                        itemCreateOperation = CreateOperation(with: viewContext)
                    }) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $itemCreateOperation) { createOperation in
                NavigationView {
                    NameEditor(item: createOperation.childObject)
                        .navigationTitle("New Item")
                }
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, createOperation.childContext)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NameViewer: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var itemUpdateOperation: UpdateOperation<Item>?
    
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text(item.name ?? "")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Item")
        .toolbar  {
            Button("Update") {
                itemUpdateOperation = UpdateOperation(withExistingObject: item, in: viewContext)
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $itemUpdateOperation) { updateOperation in
            NavigationView {
                NameEditor(item: updateOperation.childObject)
                    .navigationTitle("Update Item")
            }
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, updateOperation.childContext)
        }
    }
}

struct NameEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var childContext
    
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Information")) {
                if let name = Binding($item.name) {
                    TextField("Name", text: name)
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button() {
                try? childContext.save()
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, see my related answers:

- [How do I implement a child context (CoreData) in SwiftUI
  environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032785/7337547)
- [SwiftUI - Use @Binding with Core Data
  NSManagedObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614564/swiftui-use-binding-with-core-data-nsmanagedobject/67174011#67174011)

Comment: Interesting answer. I am not sure I like the idea of duplicating effort across viewer / editor pairs. It is natural to me to combine the functionality. The other issue with the code as presented is that it lost the ability to persist the data across app launches.

Comment: @ericg if you look at Apple’s native apps with editing functionality (e.g. Contacts, Health) they all have dedicated detail and edit views, since viewing and altering data are separate activities. Check out Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials called *Creating the Edit View* and *Working with UI Controls* for more on this. And regarding the issue that the app lost the ability to persist data across app launches, I stated in my answer that you have to save view context when the user navigates out of the app.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I need to silence this voice yelling at me saying that duplicating code is to be avoided. In my particular case, there is no reason that viewing & editing need to be separate activities in the same way it makes sense for the Contacts and Heath app, but I learned a long time ago not to fight the framework. If that is the architecture SwiftUI is pushing, that is what should be done.

Comment: @ericg you don’t have to employ that solution if you don’t see it fit in your project. It’s just a matter of scalability and architecture. Here’s [the solution](https://gist.github.com/genebogdanovich/d945b681a5bf991a20a34b3daf27d142) I came up with when we have the single view for detail as well as for editor. It solves your issue with having to click into the TextField for text to update.