# Core Data - reflect parent context changed to child context without saving child

Tags: core-data, swiftui

From here I tried to use a childContext for adding a new entity which could be thrown away if the user doesnt want to save it: [How do I implement a child context (CoreData) in SwiftUI environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977658/how-do-i-implement-a-child-context-coredata-in-swiftui-environment)

In the View for Adding there is the temporary Person Object and a List to connect a category to the Person. I wonder if it is possible to delete a category from the parent store and reflect this to the child context? **If I save the child context the new added temporary Person would be saved which is not correct**. But if I only save the parent the Category List is not updated because I think this is the reflection of the childContext, right?

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest() var persons: FetchedResults<Person>

    @State private var personCreation: CreateOperation<Ausgabe>?

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Button("add"){
                personCreation = CreateOperation(withParentContext: moc)
            }
            List(persons){p in
                Text(p.name)
            }
            .sheet(item: $personCreation){personHandler in
                AddingView(
                    personTemp: personHandler.object
                )
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, creationHandler.childContext)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddingView: View{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var childMoc
    @ObservedObject pers: Person
    @FetchRequest var persCats: FetchedResults<Pers_Category>

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            ForEach(persCats){cat in
                Text(cat.name)
                    .onTapGesture{
                        if let parentCat = context.parent?.object(with: cat.objectID){
                            childMoc.parent?.delete(parentCat)                 //<------ Here
                            try? childMoc.parent?.save()
                        }
                    }
            }
            TextField("name", text: $pers.name)
        }
    }
}




struct CreateOperation<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    let object: Object
    
    init(withParentContext parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        object = Object(context: childContext)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here

1. Configure the sheet so that it closes when the item is deleted.
2. enable automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent on the child context so that changes from the parent are merged in. Note this can also be done manually by listening for the save notification and searching for only the changes of interest.
3. Edit your model to enforce the relation and handle the error on save.

Comment: The `childContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` did it here I think. The first test looked right. Thank you!